# how to connect to haas online trading server connecting through PORT 8090 on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, port

I have an EC2 ubuntu server with haas online trading server installed which requires me to connect through PORT 8090 or 8092.

The xml file is configured as follows:

```
<HostingAdres>xx.xxx.56.78</HostingAdres>
  <ExternalAdres />
  <HostingPort>8090</HostingPort>
  <HubPort>8092</HubPort>
```

I have opened these ports with Custom TCP in the Security Groups but when I see which ports are listening with:

```
netstat -tulpn
```

I get:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::9300                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 172.31.95.106:68        0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

and I have tried:

```
sudo ufw allow 8090
ps -A|grep mono
```

produces:

```
1922 pts/0    00:00:03 mono
```

so a mono process appears to be running. the haas online server is htr only mono program.

But the port remains stubbornly unavailable.

How can I open 8090 and 8092 to accept traffic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The security group, and `netstat` are not related. Think of the security group as your network firewall. Changes to your security group do not effect what port your server is listening on, it changes what ports your network will allow incoming traffic on. For your server to be listening on ports `8090` and `8092` some sort of service/application needs to be running and bound to those ports. It looks like you have configured the haas service to listen on those ports, but you haven't started the haas service. Or perhaps you need to restart the service to get it to pick up the modified port configuration.

Comment: thanks I have edited my question. I think it is running.

Comment: I should clarify: I think the process is running on the server (haas uses the mono framework) but it is still not accessible on my-ec2-ip:8090

Comment: According to netstat, you don't have any process running that is bound to port `8090`.

Comment: indeed! Why is that? It means the process is not running?

Comment: There is insufficient information to provide an answer to that. It appears to me that the process is not running, or it is not configured correctly.

Comment: You are right it's not running. Sorry! I need to do more work on it and then i will come back and update my response. Thank you for your time.